# compare two fields in Flask Jinja2

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I am trying to compare two fields generated with Jinja, however, without the need of pressing the submit button.

I have used the included validators, standard if cases, etc. None of them work as expected, so I tried Javascript.

In general, I want to:

1. Compare two fields (domain/server). If their IP addresses are not exactly a 'Confirm' button should be shown.

In order to do that, I need to reload the server-side HTML.

2. Additionally, I am unable to figure out how to compare the two fields' IP addresses via Javascript.

Here is a sample code:

```html
<div id="home" class="text-center">
    Hello, {{ username }}
</div>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="domain" size="30">
    <input type="text" id="server" size="30">
    
    {% if not compareArecords %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button><br>
    {%endif %}
</body>
    
<script>
    document.getElementById("domain").addEventListener("keyup", compareArecords);
    document.getElementById("server").addEventListener("keyup", compareArecords);

    function compareArecords() {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("domain");
        var text2 = document.getElementById("server");
        if (text1.value === text2.value)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's typically done in order not to have to reload the html is to have the element hidden with css until you need to display it. In your example would be something like

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="domain" size="30">
    <input type="text" id="server" size="30">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hidden" id="btn-danger">Danger</button><br>
</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById("domain").addEventListener("keyup", compareArecords);
    document.getElementById("server").addEventListener("keyup", compareArecords);

    function compareArecords() {
        var text1 = document.getElementById("domain");
        var text2 = document.getElementById("server");
        if (text1.value === text2.value)
            // Nothing to do here!
        else {
            var danger_btn = document.getElementById("btn-danger");
            danger_btn.classList.toggle("hidden");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Css:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

It should be noted that you can also generate the Danger button entirely with javascript, and that's not overly complicated either, should you want to do that, but it has some drawbacks like separation of concerns.